# Strange error message on scala 2.10 / sbt 0.13 upgrade

Tags: scala, sbt, testng

We're trying to upgrade https://github.com/linkedin/play-testng-plugin to scala 2.10 / sbt 0.13, also using the new version (3.0.0 vs 2.0.3) of https://bitbucket.org/jmhofer/sbt-testng-interface/wiki/Home

However, I am getting a strange error on sbt compile which we have not been able to figure out but seems to be caused by the following code snipper:

```
class WrappedTestNGRunner(testClassLoader: ClassLoader, loggers: Array[Logger], state: TestRunState) extends TestNGRunner(testClassLoader: ClassLoader, loggers: Array[Logger], state: TestRunState) {
  override def run(testClassname: String, fingerprint: Fingerprint, eventHandler: EventHandler, testOptions: Array[String]) = {
    super.run(testClassname, fingerprint, eventHandler, testOptions)
  }
}
```

error message:

```
[error]
[error]      while compiling: /home/bliang/Projects/play-testng-plugin/plugin/src/main/scala/NGPlugin.scala
[error]         during phase: erasure
[error]      library version: version 2.10.1
[error]     compiler version: version 2.10.1
[error]   reconstructed args: -bootclasspath /export/apps/jdk/JDK-1_6_0_27/jre/lib/resources.jar:/export/apps/jdk/JDK-1_6_0_27/jre/lib/rt.jar:/export/apps/jdk/JDK-1_6_0_27/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/export/apps/jdk/JDK-1_6_0_27/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/export/apps/jdk/JDK-1_6_0_27/jre/lib/jce.jar:/export/apps/jdk/JDK-1_6_0_27/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/export/apps/jdk/JDK-1_6_0_27/jre/lib/modules/jdk.boot.jar:/export/apps/jdk/JDK-1_6_0_27/jre/classes:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.10.1.jar -classpath /home/bliang/Projects/play-testng-plugin/plugin/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0.13/classes:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/de.johoop/sbt-testng-plugin/jars/sbt-testng-plugin-3.0.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/de.johoop/sbt-testng-interface_2.10/jars/sbt-testng-interface_2.10-3.0.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/sbt/jars/sbt-0.13.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/main/jars/main-0.13.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/actions/jars/actions-0.13.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/classpath/jars/classpath-0.13.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/launcher-interface/jars/launcher-interface-0.13.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/interface/jars/interface-0.13.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/io/jars/io-0.13.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/control/jars/control-0.13.0.jar:/home/bliang/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.2/lib/scala-compiler.jar:/home/bliang/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.2/lib/scala-reflect.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/completion/jars/completion-0.13.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/collections/jars/collections-0.13.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/local/jline/jline/2.11/jars/jline.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/api/jars/api-0.13.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/compiler-integration/jars/compiler-integration-0.13.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/incremental-compiler/jars/incremental-compiler-0.13.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/logging/jars/logging-0.13.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/process/jars/process-0.13.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/relation/jars/relation-0.13.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/compile/jars/compile-0.13.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/persist/jars/persist-0.13.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-tools.sbinary/sbinary_2.10/jars/sbinary_2.10-0.4.2.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/classfile/jars/classfile-0.13.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/compiler-ivy-integration/jars/compiler-ivy-integration-0.13.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/ivy/jars/ivy-0.13.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/cross/jars/cross-0.13.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/local/org.apache.ivy/ivy/2.3.0-rc1/jars/ivy.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/local/com.jcraft/jsch/0.1.46/jars/jsch.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/run/jars/run-0.13.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/task-system/jars/task-system-0.13.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/tasks/jars/tasks-0.13.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/tracking/jars/tracking-0.13.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/cache/jars/cache-0.13.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/testing/jars/testing-0.13.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/test-agent/jars/test-agent-0.13.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/local/org.scala-sbt/test-interface/1.0/jars/test-interface.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/main-settings/jars/main-settings-0.13.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/apply-macro/jars/apply-macro-0.13.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/command/jars/command-0.13.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/compiler-interface/jars/compiler-interface-src-0.13.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/compiler-interface/jars/compiler-interface-bin-0.13.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/precompiled-2_8_2/jars/compiler-interface-bin-0.13.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/precompiled-2_9_2/jars/compiler-interface-bin-0.13.0.jar:/home/bliang/Projects/play-2.2.0-M2/repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/precompiled-2_9_3/jars/compiler-interface-bin-0.13.0.jar
[error]
[error]   last tree to typer: This(anonymous class $anonfun)
[error]               symbol: anonymous class $anonfun (flags: final <synthetic>)
[error]    symbol definition: final class $anonfun extends AbstractFunction1[ClassLoader,Unit] with Serializable
[error]        symbol owners: anonymous class $anonfun -> method apply -> anonymous class $anonfun -> method ngSettings -> object NGPlugin -> package plugin
[error]       context owners: value sharedState -> class WrappedTestNGFramework -> package plugin
[error]
[error] == Enclosing template or block ==
[error]
[error] Template( // val <local WrappedTestNGFramework>: <notype> in class WrappedTestNGFramework, tree.tpe=com.linkedin.plugin.WrappedTestNGFramework
[error]   "java.lang.Object", "org.scalatools.testing.Framework" // parents
[error]   ValDef(
[error]     private
[error]     "_"
[error]     <tpt>
[error]     <empty>
[error]   )
[error]   // 8 statements
[error]   DefDef( // def <init>(): com.linkedin.plugin.WrappedTestNGFramework in class WrappedTestNGFramework
[error]     <method>
[error]     "<init>"
[error]     []
[error]     List(Nil)
[error]     <tpt> // tree.tpe=com.linkedin.plugin.WrappedTestNGFramework
[error]     Block(
[error]       Apply( // def <init>(): Object in class Object
[error]         WrappedTestNGFramework.super."<init>" // def <init>(): Object in class Object
[error]         Nil
[error]       )
[error]       ()
[error]     )
[error]   )
[error]   ValDef( // private[this] val name: String in class WrappedTestNGFramework
[error]     private <local> <triedcooking>
[error]     "name "
[error]     <tpt> // tree.tpe=String
[error]     "TestNGFakeApp"
[error]   )
[error]   DefDef( // val name(): String in class WrappedTestNGFramework
[error]     <method> <stable> <accessor>
[error]     "name"
[error]     []
[error]     List(Nil)
[error]     <tpt> // tree.tpe=String
[error]     WrappedTestNGFramework.this."name " // private[this] val name: String in class WrappedTestNGFramework
[error]   )
[error]   ValDef( // private[this] val tests: Array[org.scalatools.testing.Fingerprint] in class WrappedTestNGFramework
[error]     private <local> <triedcooking>
[error]     "tests "
[error]     <tpt> // tree.tpe=Array[org.scalatools.testing.Fingerprint]
[error]     Apply( // def apply[T](xs: Seq[T],implicit evidence$2: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]): Array[T] in object Array, tree.tpe=Array[org.scalatools.testing.Fingerprint]
[error]       TypeApply( // def apply[T](xs: Seq[T],implicit evidence$2: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]): Array[T] in object Array, tree.tpe=(xs: Seq[org.scalatools.testing.Fingerprint], implicit evidence$2: scala.reflect.ClassTag[org.scalatools.testing.Fingerprint])Array[org.scalatools.testing.Fingerprint]
[error]         "scala"."Array"."apply" // def apply[T](xs: Seq[T],implicit evidence$2: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]): Array[T] in object Array
[error]         <tpt> // tree.tpe=org.scalatools.testing.Fingerprint
[error]       )
[error]       // 2 arguments
[error]       Apply( // implicit def wrapRefArray[T <: Object](xs: Array[T]): scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[T] in class LowPriorityImplicits, tree.tpe=Seq[org.scalatools.testing.Fingerprint]
[error]         TypeApply( // implicit def wrapRefArray[T <: Object](xs: Array[T]): scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[T] in class LowPriorityImplicits, tree.tpe=(xs: Array[org.scalatools.testing.Fingerprint])scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[org.scalatools.testing.Fingerprint]
[error]           scala.this."Predef"."wrapRefArray" // implicit def wrapRefArray[T <: Object](xs: Array[T]): scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[T] in class LowPriorityImplicits
[error]           <tpt> // tree.tpe=org.scalatools.testing.Fingerprint
[error]         )
[error]         ArrayValue(
[error]           <tpt> // tree.tpe=org.scalatools.testing.Fingerprint
[error]           List(
[error]             Apply( // def <init>(annotationName: String,isModule: Boolean): de.johoop.testnginterface.Annotated in class Annotated
[error]               new de.johoop.testnginterface.Annotated."<init>" // def <init>(annotationName: String,isModule: Boolean): de.johoop.testnginterface.Annotated in class Annotated
[error]               // 2 arguments
[error]               "com.linkedin.plugin.FakeApplication"
[error]               Apply( // def apply$default$2(): Boolean @scala.annotation.unchecked.uncheckedVariance in object Annotated
[error]                 "de"."johoop"."testnginterface"."Annotated"."apply$default$2" // def apply$default$2(): Boolean @scala.annotation.unchecked.uncheckedVariance in object Annotated
[error]                 Nil
[error]               )
[error]             )
[error]           )
[error]         )
[error]       )
[error]       Apply( // def apply[T](runtimeClass1: Class[_]): scala.reflect.ClassTag[T] in object ClassTag, tree.tpe=scala.reflect.ClassTag[org.scalatools.testing.Fingerprint]
[error]         TypeApply( // def apply[T](runtimeClass1: Class[_]): scala.reflect.ClassTag[T] in object ClassTag, tree.tpe=(runtimeClass1: Class[_])scala.reflect.ClassTag[org.scalatools.testing.Fingerprint]
[error]           "ClassTag"."apply" // def apply[T](runtimeClass1: Class[_]): scala.reflect.ClassTag[T] in object ClassTag
[error]           <tpt> // tree.tpe=org.scalatools.testing.Fingerprint
[error]         )
[error]         classOf[org.scalatools.testing.Fingerprint]
[error]       )
[error]     )
[error]   )
[error]   DefDef( // val tests(): Array[org.scalatools.testing.Fingerprint] in class WrappedTestNGFramework
[error]     <method> <stable> <accessor>
[error]     "tests"
[error]     []
[error]     List(Nil)
[error]     <tpt> // tree.tpe=Array[org.scalatools.testing.Fingerprint]
[error]     WrappedTestNGFramework.this."tests " // private[this] val tests: Array[org.scalatools.testing.Fingerprint] in class WrappedTestNGFramework
[error]   )
[error]   DefDef( // def testRunner(testClassLoader: ClassLoader,loggers: Array[org.scalatools.testing.Logger]): com.linkedin.plugin.WrappedTestNGRunner in class WrappedTestNGFramework
[error]     <method>
[error]     "testRunner"
[error]     []
[error]     // 1 parameter list
[error]     ValDef( // testClassLoader: ClassLoader
[error]       <param> <triedcooking>
[error]       "testClassLoader"
[error]       <tpt> // tree.tpe=ClassLoader
[error]       <empty>
[error]     )
[error]     ValDef( // loggers: Array[org.scalatools.testing.Logger]
[error]       <param> <triedcooking>
[error]       "loggers"
[error]       <tpt> // tree.tpe=Array[org.scalatools.testing.Logger]
[error]       <empty>
[error]     )
[error]     <tpt> // tree.tpe=com.linkedin.plugin.WrappedTestNGRunner
[error]     Apply( // def <init>(testClassLoader: ClassLoader,loggers: Array[org.scalatools.testing.Logger],state: de.johoop.testnginterface.TestRunState): com.linkedin.plugin.WrappedTestNGRunner in class WrappedTestNGRunner
[error]       new com.linkedin.plugin.WrappedTestNGRunner."<init>" // def <init>(testClassLoader: ClassLoader,loggers: Array[org.scalatools.testing.Logger],state: de.johoop.testnginterface.TestRunState): com.linkedin.plugin.WrappedTestNGRunner in class WrappedTestNGRunner
[error]       // 3 arguments
[error]       "testClassLoader" // testClassLoader: ClassLoader
[error]       "loggers" // loggers: Array[org.scalatools.testing.Logger]
[error]       WrappedTestNGFramework.this."sharedState" // private[this] val sharedState: de.johoop.testnginterface.TestRunState in class WrappedTestNGFramework
[error]     )
[error]   )
[error]   ValDef( // private[this] val sharedState: de.johoop.testnginterface.TestRunState in class WrappedTestNGFramework
[error]     private <local> <triedcooking>
[error]     "sharedState"
[error]     <tpt> // tree.tpe=de.johoop.testnginterface.TestRunState
[error]     Apply( // def <init>(): de.johoop.testnginterface.TestRunState in class TestRunState, tree.tpe=de.johoop.testnginterface.TestRunState
[error]       new de.johoop.testnginterface.TestRunState."<init>" // def <init>(): de.johoop.testnginterface.TestRunState in class TestRunState, tree.tpe=()de.johoop.testnginterface.TestRunState
[error]       Nil
[error]     )
[error]   )
[error]   DefDef( // def testRunner(x$1: ClassLoader,x$2: Array[org.scalatools.testing.Logger]): org.scalatools.testing.Runner in class WrappedTestNGFramework
[error]     <method> <bridge>
[error]     "testRunner"
[error]     []
[error]     // 1 parameter list
[error]     ValDef( // x$1: ClassLoader
[error]       <param> <synthetic>
[error]       "x$1"
[error]       <tpt> // tree.tpe=ClassLoader
[error]       <empty>
[error]     )
[error]     ValDef( // x$2: Array[org.scalatools.testing.Logger]
[error]       <param> <synthetic>
[error]       "x$2"
[error]       <tpt> // tree.tpe=Array[org.scalatools.testing.Logger]
[error]       <empty>
[error]     )
[error]     <tpt> // tree.tpe=org.scalatools.testing.Runner
[error]     Apply( // def testRunner(testClassLoader: ClassLoader,loggers: Array[org.scalatools.testing.Logger]): com.linkedin.plugin.WrappedTestNGRunner in class WrappedTestNGFramework
[error]       WrappedTestNGFramework.this."testRunner" // def testRunner(testClassLoader: ClassLoader,loggers: Array[org.scalatools.testing.Logger]): com.linkedin.plugin.WrappedTestNGRunner in class WrappedTestNGFramework
[error]       // 2 arguments
[error]       "x$1" // x$1: ClassLoader
[error]       "x$2" // x$2: Array[org.scalatools.testing.Logger]
[error]     )
[error]   )
[error] )
[error]
[error] uncaught exception during compilation: scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeError
[error] /home/bliang/Projects/play-testng-plugin/helpers/src/main/java/com/linkedin/plugin/NGTests.java:119: cannot find symbol
[error] symbol  : constructor FakeApplication(java.io.File,java.lang.ClassLoader,java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>,java.util.List<java.lang.String>)
[error] location: class play.test.FakeApplication
[error]         return new FakeApplication(new File(path), Helpers.class.getClassLoader(), getConf(), getPlugins());
[error]                ^
[error] Note: /home/bliang/Projects/play-testng-plugin/helpers/src/main/java/com/linkedin/plugin/NGTests.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[error] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[error] 1 error
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last play-plugins-testng/compile:compile for the full output.
[error] (play-plugins-testng/compile:compile) scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeError: bad symbolic reference. A signature in EventRecorder.class refers to term testng
[error] in package org which is not available.
[error] It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
[error] the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling EventRecorder.class.
[error] (play-testng-helpers/compile:compile) javac returned nonzero exit code
[error] Total time: 4 s, completed Aug 28, 2013 5:36:20 PM
```

diff is below:

```
diff --git a/plugin/src/main/scala/NGPlugin.scala b/plugin/src/main/scala/NGPlugin.scala
index e3f7c67d5386c3737ea5c4c31c30e83a47111471..89ae5687d371e0b353dd39f869d31afb81844085 100644
--- a/plugin/src/main/scala/NGPlugin.scala
+++ b/plugin/src/main/scala/NGPlugin.scala
@@ -44,7 +44,7 @@ object NGPlugin extends Plugin {
        libraryDependencies <++= (testNGVersion in Test)(v => Seq(
          "org.testng" % "testng" % v % "test->default",
          // If changing this, be sure to change in Build.scala also.
-         "de.johoop" %% "sbt-testng-interface" % "2.0.3" % "test"))
+         "de.johoop" % "sbt-testng-interface_2.10" % "3.0.0" % "test"))
   )

   private def playLoggerClass(loader: ClassLoader) = {
@@ -74,4 +74,4 @@ class WrappedTestNGRunner(testClassLoader: ClassLoader, loggers: Array[Logger],
   override def run(testClassname: String, fingerprint: Fingerprint, eventHandler: EventHandler, testOptions: Array[String]) = {
     super.run(testClassname, fingerprint, eventHandler, testOptions)
   }
-}
+}
\ No newline at end of file
diff --git a/project/Build.scala b/project/Build.scala
index aee26f3af24644fa9bdb39f1d317a91b60d2618c..2a62dd04be0a68aab11c0b07edaf8e0c283afcf7 100644
--- a/project/Build.scala
+++ b/project/Build.scala
@@ -21,6 +21,7 @@ object NGPluginBuild extends Build {
                             url(ArtifactoryBaseUrl + "CORE"))(LinkedInPatterns)

     val typeSafeReleases = "TypeSafeRelease" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
+    val sonaTypeReleases = "Sonatype OSS Releases" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"
   }

   lazy val root = Project("root", file("."),
@@ -34,7 +35,7 @@ object NGPluginBuild extends Build {
     settings = commonSettings ++ Seq(
       libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
         "org.testng" % "testng" % "6.4", // % "provided"
-        "play" %% "play-test" % "2012.09.20.1886ca6" //% "provided"
+        "play" % "play-test_2.10" % "2.2-SNAPSHOT" //% "provided"
       )))

   lazy val NGPlugin = Project(
@@ -45,16 +46,16 @@ object NGPluginBuild extends Build {
       libraryDependencies <++= (scalaVersion, sbtVersion) { 
         case (scalaVersion, sbtVersion) => Seq(
           // If changing this, be sure to change in NGPlugin.scala also.
-          sbtPluginExtra("de.johoop" % "sbt-testng-plugin" % "2.0.3", "0.12", scalaVersion),
-          "de.johoop" %% "sbt-testng-interface" % "2.0.3"
+          sbtPluginExtra("de.johoop" % "sbt-testng-plugin" % "3.0.0", "0.13", "2.10"),
+          "de.johoop" % "sbt-testng-interface_2.10" % "3.0.0"
         )
       }))

   lazy val commonSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = Project.defaultSettings ++ publishSettings ++ Seq(
     organization := "com.linkedin",
-    scalaVersion := "2.9.2",
+    scalaVersion := "2.10.1",
     version := "2012.09.20.1886ca6-v5",
-    resolvers ++= Seq(Repos.localRepo, Repos.sandbox, Repos.typeSafeReleases))
+    resolvers ++= Seq(Repos.localRepo, Repos.sandbox, Repos.typeSafeReleases, Repos.sonaTypeReleases))

   lazy val publishSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(
     // publishTo <<= version { (v: String) =>
diff --git a/project/build.properties b/project/build.properties
index a8c2f849be3cf976d18427f666d9e6d433d189b2..0974fce44da5f8a84f7e1efe6aff9ebb25d128f6 100755
--- a/project/build.properties
+++ b/project/build.properties
@@ -1 +1 @@
-sbt.version=0.12.0
+sbt.version=0.13.0
diff --git a/sample/project/build.properties b/sample/project/build.properties
index a8c2f849be3cf976d18427f666d9e6d433d189b2..0974fce44da5f8a84f7e1efe6aff9ebb25d128f6 100644
--- a/sample/project/build.properties
+++ b/sample/project/build.properties
@@ -1 +1 @@
-sbt.version=0.12.0
+sbt.version=0.13.0
```

Comment: can you add a TL;DR; at the top please?

Comment: @PaulNikonowicz updated with a shorter synopsis

Answer (score 2):

the compile error is caused by a change in the signature of FakeApplication(...).

```
Uncaught exception during compilation: scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeError
[error] /home/bliang/Projects/play-testng-plugin/helpers/src/main/java/com/linkedin/plugin/NGTests.java:119: cannot find symbol
[error] symbol  : constructor FakeApplication(java.io.File,java.lang.ClassLoader,java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>,java.util.List<java.lang.String>)
[error] location: class play.test.FakeApplication
[error]         return new FakeApplication(new File(path), Helpers.class.getClassLoader(), getConf(), getPlugins());
```

You need to change

```
return new FakeApplication(new File(path), Helpers.class.getClassLoader(), getConf(), getPlugins());
```

to

```
return new FakeApplication(new File(path), Helpers.class.getClassLoader(), getConf(), getPlugins(), null);
```

in NGTest.java: 119

You may also encounter classpath issues due to different versions of play in the classpath.
The groupId of Play was changed 2.2.x from "play" to "com.typesafe.play", which may be a problem since sbt will consider diffferent versions of play-* to be different artifacts, and therefore will NOT detect conflicting versions.

Comment: The first suggestion worked as expected - I just wasn't sure what to put for the missing argument. However, after looking at the other error, I realised that the line "reconstructed args: -bootclasspath..." doesn't have testng in it. I've tried both testng versions 6.4 and 6.8.5 (which is what our dependent sbt-testng-interface uses) in our project, and does seem that they are getting downloaded into the local ivy cache, but for some reason it's still not getting picked up by the classpath. This is very puzzling. Can you think of any reason why it might not be able to find the testng artifact?

Comment: @omnilinguist the code causing the problem was just dead, so I removed it and everything seems to be woking just fine.

Comment: I also published my version on this branch: https://github.com/linkedin/play-testng-plugin/tree/play_22. Test are all OK in the sample app

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, figured out how to get around this. I had to add

```
"org.testng" % "testng" % "6.4", // both 6.4 and 6.8.5 seem to work
```

to the NGPlugin libaryDependencies. In retrospect, this only makes sense, since EventRecorder in sbt-testng-interface has a compile dependency on org.testng . However, I have no idea how this was working before, since the previous version of sbt-testng-interface we depended on (2.0.3) also has that dependency as far as I could tell.